# Is it good practice to let nginx serve files from his directory in /tmp?

Tags: linux, nginx, http

I need nginx to serve processed gif files. I have two ideas:

- Move files to a directory in /var/www and let nginx serve them from there

  - Create a dir in /tmp (pros: automatic cleanup after each restart, etc)

Which one should I use?

Comment: As `/tmp` is shared it can create security problems. I would advise a specific directory used only for this need and available only to `nginx`.

Comment: yeah, but I created an special directory for nginx in tmp, and set it to nginx root. Is it still bad?

Comment: If only `nginx` can access it, then it is great, as long as you remember it is not persisting upon reboots, so you need something that recreates it before `nginx` starts. And remembering not to put things there that you need. If you use `systemd`, have a look at `systemd-tmpfiles`

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `/tmp` is shared by default, but systemd will happily provide a private `/tmp` directory for any service it manages. This is probably already in place for your copy of nginx. No need to get into `systemd-tmpfiles`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is why I recommended to OP to look at this feature of `systemd`, as in his question he refers to `/tmp` explicitely, so he might not be aware of it. Or if `nginx` has it automatically, as locally installed, yes. Not enough data in question to know with distribution, version, etc.

Comment: Thank you all. About systemd-tmp - I can't use it - files are generated by a PHP script, so this cannot be private nginx's dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/tmp is shared by default. You can probably make it work out of there, but probably better to use a more traditional document root. If you want the files to be cleared out with any regularity you could just clear the directory with a scheduled script.